# How do I use threadpools for fileIO?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, file-io, threadpool

I'm interested in doing asynchronous reads from a large file, especially using calls to CreateThreadpoolIo(), StartThreadpoolIo(), etc.  However, my mental model for how to structure such a thing is very ill-defined.  I've sought out and found examples of the usage of these functions on github, but inevitably their usage is pretty obfuscated by the complexity of the surrounding code, so I'm having difficulty understanding all that's going on.

Would someone be able to provide me a no-frills toy example for their usage, combined with CreateFile2(), ReadFile() and perhaps any other necessary functions?

Comment: Use Overlapped I/O or an I/O Completion Port for handling asynchronous I/O.  Your can use a thread pool to handle the status notifications from `GetOverlappedResult()` or `GetQueuedCompletetionStatus()`. Read MSDN for details: [Synchronous and Asynchronous I/O](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365683.aspx), [Synchronization and Overlapped Input and Output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686358.aspx), [I/O Completion Ports](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198.aspx), etc.

Comment: StackOverflow is not meant for asking people to write code and examples/tutorials for you.  Please do some research and write your own code first, and then ask specific questions about any problems you have with it.

Comment: I was hesitant to ask this for that reason.  Still, my hope was that trying this might be better than asking N more specific questions in quick succession, as I would likely have to do given how novice I am on this topic.